# comment faire pour déploie un projet Nextjs in MacBook 13.10?

Tags: next.js

je veux crée un projet sur Nextjs 14 ,tout on téléchargent Node 18 et mon système d'exploitation est MacBook 13.10 mais je me suis retrouve bloque car les versions (celle de système ,de Node et Nextjs) ne sont pas compatible.
Que dois-je faire ?

j'ai essaye de change la version de Node mais c'était impossible.

Comment: Bonjour, bienvenu sur Stackoverflow! Uniquement les questions en anglais sont admises ici. Aussi, essayez d'ajouter des messages d'erreur et un moyen de reproduire dans votre question !